# Ignore validation of id_token during Authorization Code flow for OpenIdConnect

Tags: asp.net-core, openid-connect

I'm having an issue with an OpenIdConnect integration whereby the incoming `id_token` isn't able to be decoded/unprotected during the login process. I'm wondering if this validation can be bypassed or skipped within .NET Core's OpenIdConnect Middleware for individual integrations.

The flow that is in place for the integration is the Authorization Code flow, which as I understand suggests that the `id_token` is validated against before the userinfo endpoint is called (documented here: https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#CodeFlowSteps).

The flow appears to work well in regards obtaining the `id_token`, however it appears to fail when it is trying to be decode/unprotect the `id_token`. I traced the error here:

```
trce: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler[24]

      MessageReceived: '?code=21400ee5-dd4c-447e-9e09-bbcd081b7f8c'.

dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler[13]

      Updating configuration

trce: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler[27]

      Authorization code received.

dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler[19]

      Redeeming code for tokens.

trce: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler[30]

      Token response received.

fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler[17]

      Exception occurred while processing message.

      Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenSignatureKeyNotFoundException: IDX10500: Signature validation failed. No security keys were provided to validate the signature.

         at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateSignature(String token, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)

         at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken(String token, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters, SecurityToken& validatedToken)

         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.ValidateToken(String idToken, AuthenticationProperties properties, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters, JwtSecurityToken& jwt)

         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.HandleRemoteAuthenticateAsync()
```

As you can see, the error appears to be:

```
IDX10500: Signature validation failed. No security keys were provided to validate the signature.
```

If it helps to understand my context, I have an environment set-up where I have added the following which allows me to have multiple integrations within my environment:

```
services.AddAuthentication().AddOpenIdConnect( ......
```

I have tried adding the following to the individual integration however that appeared to make no impact:

```
instance.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
{
    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false
};
```

Unfortunately I am not the one in control of the `id_token` value so I am unable to resolve the issue with the `id_token` itself. As such, is it possible to ignore the `id_token` validation to allow for the flow to continue? Additionally, if this is possible then what realistically are the security implications of doing this?

Comment: What service is used to issue the token (authorization server)?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know the definitive answer as the authorization server is one of my client's. I do know that they have built a completely custom solution. I'll try to obtain the information from my client.

Comment: I guess your client can't access the public key needed to verify the received token?

Comment: Correct. My client wasn't able to provide a .well-known configuration file, as such I have had to craft one for them which includes URLs to their endpoints. The client doesn't have a jwks_uri endpoint, so no public key is available for the unprotecting of the received id_token.

Comment: you use the same key for verifying the received access token, sure you can create your own JWKS in case they can provide the private or public key in some other format.

Comment: My client isn't in a position to provide the public key as they the developer themselves do not have exposure to it. It has been decided that the client is going to seek help on their side to provide the jwks_uri endpoint, which should hopefully solve the issue. Regardless thanks for your advice!

Comment: Ok, they should be able to share the public key (if the know how to work with keys), sharing the public key with the world is not a security problem, everyone does that....